# SwiftUI TextField textInputAutocapitalization not working for uppercased text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to make all characters uppercased on TextField and I tried to use `textInputAutocapitalization` . I see that on my device that has iOS 17.3.1 does nothing, I tried with `textInputAutocapitalization(.characters)` or `textInputAutocapitalization(.words)` , nothing. I see that on a simulator with 17.2 works perfectly.

Does anyone know if there is a bug? I can't find anything about this and I don't have another device with other OS to test.

I tried also to have a workaround by doing this, but the problem is that when I want to modify something in the middle of the text, the cursor goes to the end of the text after each character...

```
struct GeneralTextField: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var textCase: Text.Case
    
    TextField("", text: $text)
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                if textCase == .uppercase {
                    let uppercasedValue = newValue.uppercased()
                    if uppercasedValue != text {
                        text = uppercasedValue
                    }
                } else if textCase == .lowercase {
                    let lowerCased = newValue.lowercased()
                    if lowerCased != text {
                        text = lowerCased
                    }
               }
            }
            //.textInputAutocapitalization(.characters)
}
```

Comment: May I ask where 'textCase' comes from?

Comment: It's a variable that I send to the view of type Text.Case, as I have only some fields where I want to be uppercased. I'll update the description

Comment: `.textInputAutocapitalization(.characters)` works for me.